# How do you add similar posts to a detail page using django

Tags: python, django

I tried to show similar posts to an article in an aside column. A feauture sites like youtube and even stack overflow. Not having anyone to ask about it, I assumed articles listed on the side were ones with similar tags. But it's not working its saying nothing matches. this is what I had in my post_detail.html:

```
{% block content %}

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 70px">

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        {% if instance.image %}
            <img src='{{ instance.image.url }}' class="img-responsive" />
        {% endif %}


    <p>Share on:
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">
    Facebook
    </a>

    <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status={{ instance.content | truncatechars:80 | urlify }}%20{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">
     Twitter
    </a>


    <a href='https://plus.google.com/share?url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}'></a>


    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}&title={{
    instance.title }}&summary={{ share_string }}&source={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">
     Linkedin
    </a>
    </p>

        <h1>{{ title }}<small>{% if instance.draft %}<span style="color:red"> Draft</span>{% endif %} {{instance.publish}}</small></h1>


        {% if instance.user.get_full_name %}
        <p>By {{ instance.user.get_full_name }}</p>
        {% else %}
            <p>Author {{ instance.user }}</p>
        {% endif  %}

        <p><a href='{% url "posts:list" %}'>Back</a></p>
        <p><a href='{% url "posts:delete" instance.id %}'>delete</a></p>
        <p>{{instance.content | linebreaks }}</p>
        <hr> 

    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default pull-right" style="height: 1000px">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Similar Articles</h3>
      </div>
      ==========right here====================
        <div class="panel-body">
            {% for tag in instance.tags.all %}
            <h4> <a href="{% url 'posts:detail' slug=tag.slug %}"> {{ tag.title }}</a>  </h4><hr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
       ==========right here====================
    </div>


</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

and this is my view

```
 def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if instance.publish > timezone.now().date() or instance.draft:
        if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
            raise Http404
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)
    context = {
        "title": "detail",
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
    }
    return render(request, "posts/post_detail.html", context)
```

if this approach is beyond syntax correction and needs to be rewritten. I don't mind writing it over the correct way. This is my second month working with Django. To me this way made sense but it's not working. And are sites like youtube which has a video and similar videos to the right of the main video, are those videos there because they share similar tags? any and all help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should let us know what is not matching.

your `post_detail` tries to find a Post with a tag's slug.

`instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)`

I doubt that's what you intended.

`get_object_or_404` either tries to find an exact match or raise error.
Since your original post has the tag, you will be getting the same post or multiple.

The following block of code is not what you said you wanted either.

```
        {% for tag in instance.tags.all %}
        <h4> <a href="{% url 'posts:detail' slug=tag.slug %}"> {{ tag.title }}</a>  </h4><hr>
        {% endfor %}
```

It lists all tags of the original post, doesn't list related post (via tag)

If you want to show related post, and you intent to use `tag` to define `relatedness`, define a method in your post model to return such related posts.

```
def get_related_posts_by_tags(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(tags__in=self.tags.all())
```

> are those videos there because they share similar tags?

Not sure how they judge the relatedness, you should ask that in a separate question.
If I have to guess, it would be more than just tag comparison though.

** edit

Actually, proper term for `relatedness` is `similarity`.

You might find further info by googling `document similarity`.

```
{% for post in instance.get_related_post_by_tag %}
// href to post.absolute_url
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thats a new word for my vocabulary and that's the term I've been looking for. How do I show relatedness. I don't know how or what sites base their relatedness on. I thought it was based off of tags.Your way seems good, but how do I link to the posts returned from Post.objects.filter(tags__in=self.tags.all()) ?

Answer (score 4):

In the long run and to not reinvent the wheel using a reusable Django application already tried and tested is the sensible approach. In your case there is such app: [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit)
and is easy to use:

1. You install it

   ```
   pip install django-taggit
   ```
2. Add it to your installed apps:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       ...
       'taggit',
   ]
   ```
3. Add its custom manager to the model on which you want tags

   ```
   from django.db import models

   from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

   class YourModel(models.Model):
       # ... fields here

       tags = TaggableManager()
   ```

   and you can use it in your views:

   ```
   all_tabs = instance.tags.all()
   ```

It even has a [`similar_objects()`](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#TaggableManager.similar_objects) method which:

> Returns a list (not a lazy QuerySet) of other objects tagged similarly
>   to this one, ordered with most similar first.

**EDIT**

To retrieve similar posts you should use:

```
similar_posts = instance.tags.similar_objects()
```

and to get only the first, let's say, 5 similar posts:

```
similar_posts = instance.tags.similar_objects()[:5]
```

where `instance` is a instance of the `Post` model.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But how do I link back to the posts that are similar? I will end up switching to taggit, as I have been suggested to use this before

Comment: tried using this and it broke my app. I  have to use it in the beginning . I have only been using Django for about two months now. I am following a tutorial so I'm copying how he does it. just tried messing with it for an hour . but thanks

Comment: does similar_objects() remove the same post in similar posts because nobody want to see same post in similar posts.